# How to make effectful computation referential transparent

Tags: scala, io, functional-programming, scalaz, scala-cats

I'm learning FP by writing simple apps. And now I'm approaching effect monads (`cats.effect.IO`/`scalaz.IO` does not really matter). I have two functions:

```
def open(path: String): IO[InputStream] = IO {
  new FileInputStream(new File(path))
}

def read(is: InputStream): IO[Option[Array[Byte]]] = IO {
  val buffer = new Array[Byte](4096)
  val bytesRead = is.read(buffer)
  if (bytesRead != -1) {
    val newBuffer = new Array[Byte](bytesRead)
    System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, newBuffer, 0, bytesRead)
    print(new String(buffer))
    Some(newBuffer)
  }
  else
    None
}
```

And I can combine them into a stream as follows

```
import cats.effect.IO
import fs2.Stream

object App {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = logic.unsafeRunSync()

    def logic: IO[Unit] = for {
      is <- open("/tmp/prompthooks.py")
      _ <- fs2.Stream.eval(read(is)).repeat.unNoneTerminate.compile.drain
    } yield ()
}
```

And it works fine. But the question is if it all implemented in pure FP. I have doubts about that in a sense that def `read(is: InputStream): IO[Option[Array[Byte]]` accepts stream and try to read from it. Yes it suspends side-effect but in `val io = read(is)` is sort of stateful (if we perform `unsafeRunSync` twice we got different result.

Comment: It's impossible to suppress statefulness. If we didn't have state, nothing could ever work; I wouldn't be able to update this question's state by adding a comment to it. The whole point of FP is to treat programs as stateless computations with IO attached on the "edges" (stuff that goes in and out, as the term "IO" says itself). It's completely fine to e.g. obtain a Task or a Stream from some database query and pass it around the code as a value, and unpack it at "the end of the world" (e.g. at the point of returning the API response).

Comment: So as long as the side-effects are suspended, your code is perfectly fine. You will always have requests that will cause side-effects and/or return two different results on two consecutive calls, thus failing referential transparency. What you can and should do is simply try to capture this and propagate it to the very last point that you can. For example, a lot of REST framework libraries (e.g. Play, Finch, Http4s etc) will allow you to define your endpoints as functions which return a Future or a Task. This way the framework itself does the "dirty work"; you never unsafeRunSync yourself.

Comment: @slouc Good explanation, thanks!